# How can I upload a video to YouYube using the Youtube API in C#?

Tags: c#, video, upload, youtube, youtube-api

The code below fails? What might be the problem?

```
 YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("whatwill come here ?",
                "my api key",
                "my youtube login email", "my youtube login password");
        YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

Video newVideo = new Video();

newVideo.Title = "test 1";
            newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Gaming", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
            newVideo.Keywords = "test 1 , test 2";

            newVideo.Description = "test 3 test 4";
            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
            newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("tag 1, tag 2",
              YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));

            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Location = new GeoRssWhere(37, -122);


            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("C:\\test.avi", "video/quicktime");         



                Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
```

---

I solved the problem. It was my category: the category has to be *Games* instead of *Gaming*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [YouTube API integration ASP.NET - upload video with a single page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629435/youtube-api-integration-asp-net-upload-video-with-a-single-page)

Comment: i saw that. but it does not explain how to use youtube api. how do i integrate it ? i downloaded and installed YouTube SDK (1.7.0.1).msi

Comment: Hi MonsterMMORPG Shall i have the tutorial or Code regarding upload videos on YouTube. I am stuck with the Client_secret.json file.. Your guidance will be appreciated... Pls Help me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your "Gaming" category.  Amend your `MediaCategory` constructor to the following:

```
newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Games", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
```

and it should work for you.