# asp.net upload video to youtube

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, youtube

I am trying to upload a video file to Youtube and display it on my website. But I havent done uploading yet, I think displaying it is easy. Please help me with the uploading. I read many pages about this ı am so confused. İf it is possible, I just want to do it with post method without using google libraries.

Here is my simple html form in aspx file

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<div>
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="token_value"/>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="go" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
```

What should I do in the code behind? any usefull links?

Comment: why not to use proper APIs? why re-inventing the wheel? see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629435/youtube-api-integration-asp-net-upload-video-with-a-single-page